# Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server, apache2 crashing

Tags: server, apache2

I used Ubuntu 16.04 and encountered weird error with Apache2, where it don't start anymore and I cannot figure out what is causing this. Hopefully someone with fresh eyes could help me in here.

Here are some errors which I received:

```
>sudo service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then here is printout from those two status commands:

```
$sudo systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-08-24 19:15:41 CEST; 2min 35s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8631 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           └─8645 [pdflush-0

Aug 24 19:15:21 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Aug 24 19:15:21 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8631]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Aug 24 19:15:41 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8631]:  *
Aug 24 19:15:41 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8631]:  * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
Aug 24 19:15:41 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 24 19:15:41 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 24 19:15:41 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 24 19:15:41 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

sudo journalctl -xe
Aug 24 19:20:03 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Aug 24 19:20:03 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8768]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8768]:  *
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8768]:  * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu sudo[8736]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

And config test for apache looks to be clean (if don't count servername warning)

```
apachectl configtest
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

What is even more interesting is that apache2 error.log is empty

Here is output of journalctl (which I shrinked down a bit where it was repeating same stuff for Apache2 due the my trials to get it running). It looks that this is not telling much either, weird.

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-08-22 21:52:44 CEST, end at Sat 2018-08-25 13:25:11 CEST. --
Aug 24 19:20:03 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Aug 24 19:20:03 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8768]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8768]:  *
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu apache2[8768]:  * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 24 19:20:23 tegra-ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please post the output of `journalctl -u apache2.service` by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's getting even more interested.

If I set apache2 to start without document root check with command

```
apache2ctl -T
```

and then use following command to start apache, it starts without errors.

```
systemctl start apache2.service
```

but after reboot of machine apache2 is not started automatically as it should be and error again is the same. Any idea what is happening there now?